# Using form elements alone

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to print Ext form elements alone, without any layout components?

Example:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src='ext-all.js'></script> <!-- all ext instances -->
        <script type='javascript'>
        Ext.onReady(function() { /* here I would create ext object 
like a textfield to draw to div id='object' */});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Your name: <div id='object'></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

An work friend says that isn't possible and I didn't find nothing related on web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but what about utilizing the `renderTo` property?

```
Ext.onReady(function() { 
    var myField = new Ext.form.TextField({
        renderTo: 'object',
        value: 'Márcio',
        hideLabel: true,
    });
});
```

Again, I haven't tried it myself and I don't know how you will get the value outside ExtJS, but I think it should be possible.

Comment: That's it ! Such a easy solution but I'm not that good with ext. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var txtobj = document.createElement("INPUT");
var divobj = document.getElementById("object");
divobj.appendChild(txtobj);
```

copy and paste above code in your javascript function, it should work.

Comment: Buddy, you don't understood. I want it in EXT.